# Windows Notepad's search string is saved somewhere

Tags: windows, notepad

I frequently search within notepad for a string. After a few searches Notepad brings that string by default into the search window. That means that string is saved somewhere.

Anyone have a clue where that string might be stored?

Thanks

Comment: If the answer work you can accept it by clicking the tick on left side.

Answer (score 1):

Those are stored in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Notepad` registry key in `searchString` registry value. Here is a sample of that registry:

```ini
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Notepad]
"searchString"="hello"
"replaceString"="world"
```